# ELKI data generator and outliers

Tags: data-mining, outliers, elki

I want to make a test for LOF, showing how well it manages the dense-sparse problem of a dataset. In the tutorial of ELKI data generator I am shown how to make a dataset from a xml file like this with 4 clusters:

```
<dataset random-seed="1" test-model="1">
<cluster name="Dense" size="290">
<normal mean="0.5" stddev="0.2"/>
<normal mean="0.5" stddev="0.2"/>
<clip min="0 0" max="1 1"/>
</cluster>

<cluster name="Sparse" size="100">
<normal mean="0.25" stddev="0.05"/>
<normal mean="0.75" stddev="0.05"/>
<clip min="0 0" max="1 1"/>
</cluster>

<cluster name="Middle" size="100">
<normal mean="0.75" stddev="0.05"/>
<normal mean="0.75" stddev="0.05"/>
<clip min="0 0" max="1 1"/>
</cluster>

<cluster name="Noise" size="10" density-correction="50">
<uniform min="0" max="1"/>
<uniform min="0" max="1"/>
</cluster>
</dataset>
```

But how do I get a hold on the outliers. The ELKI tool want a minority label for the outliers to show a ROCAUC curve. And the file I get out of the xml file is just a file of points in the data set.

Should I then make a plot and identify the outliers myself and put a yes or no after them all to say whether they are outliers or not and set the minority label to yes, being outliers OR is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

ELKI will *default* to using the smallest class for evaluation. (You can configure evaluation differently!)

ELKI will issue a warning if the outliers are more than 5% of the data, since it is assumed that outliers are rare (they should be much less than 5%, actually).

So on your data set, ELKI should default to using "Noise" as outlier class.

In your configuration `Noise` should be 2% of the data set, so it should not warn. It should simply work out of the box.

Comment: Is it correctly understood, that the ELKI data generator only generates clusters in 2D with their labels? I could put random features in the outputfile and get a multidimensional dataset. But then I find it hard to control an experiment, since I am not sure the outlier I will place is a true outlier in X dimensions. How do researchers test that in multidimensions? I guess a start is always 2D and 3D.

Comment: No, you can generate as many dimensions as you want. There are example with 640d on the website. Just add additional distributions to all clusters.
We've experimented with such data sets, but results on synthetic data are not particularly useful. It is hard to generate a data set that is neither too easy nor impossible; and the chances of overfitting your method to your data generator (e.g. Gaussian mixture models) are massive.